# Change size of the checkbox in mat-select multiple

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am currently building an angular application. I used mat-select in my project but checkboxes are not coming as expected. Did this using  https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

[image]

This is my code

```
<mat-select class="c-input" multiple>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I search questions already on StackOverflow but didn't find a satisfying answer. I hope someone answers this.

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change size of the checkbox, you need to edit this class `.mat-pseudo-checkbox`

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox {
    width: 35px !important; //set your own size
    height: 35px !important;
}
```

And for manipulate the `✓` you can edit the `mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked::after`  class:

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked::after {
    top: 12.4px !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    width: 24px!important;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nogzxd-j3frca?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) is working example

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems like some CSS class has overridden the mat-select options. However, we can directly add the desired classes on the **.mat-pseudo-checkbox** class with the below codes:

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox{
    width: 26px !important; //needed !important to override the default behavior
    height: 26px !important; // add your own desired width and height
     
}
```

Or

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Here's the working sample working [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brbhct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.css)